# How to store selected images from gallery in singleton in android

Tags: android, singleton

I'm a beginner in android that's why i spent much of time to found the solution . My problem is how to save selected images from gallery in singleton because i need them in an onother activity. 
please someone can help me ?

Comment: Create Bitmap object in Singleton class, and assign image to this Bitmap when selecting image from Bitmap.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't... saving Bitmaps in the RAM might cause problems such as OutOfMemory exceptions. Instead, I suggest you use an image caching library such as Glide or Picasso.

Comment: You should rather put just the filepath/uri in the intent used to launch the other activity and read it disk there